# Why are angular templates showing up one above the other in the same page in mobile view?

Tags: angular, angular-template, router-outlet

I am new to Angular and I have written the code for a simple login to home screen workflow using Angular 5 and springboot. In desktop view, it looks OK. But, when I switch to mobile view using F12, each template is stacking up on the previously clicked template.
For eg:, Login screen appears below home screen.

I have already checked my app-route.module.ts and home-route.module.ts as shown below.

**app-route.module.ts**

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
       path: '',
       loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule'
    },
    {
        path: 'login',
        loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule'
    }
];
export const ROUTING: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, 
    { useHash: true });
```

**home-route.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
       path: '',
       component: HomeComponent,
       children: [
       { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
]
    }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div>
  <session-timeout-modal></session-timeout-modal>
  <!-- side navbar -->


  <div id="content" class="custom-container-width" [class.hide- 
content]="!isNaviClose" [class.loginView]="!isLoggedInForView">

    <!-- header -->
    <app-header *ngIf="isLoggedInForView"></app-header>

<!--     <sidebar-nav [class.height-content]="isNaviClose" 
  *ngIf="isLoggedInForView" (logout)="logOut()" 
  [isLoggedInForView]="isLoggedInForView"
      (sideBarChange)="naviChecker($event)"></sidebar-nav> -->

   <div class="container container-icons-home "  style="margin-left:100px" 
   *ngIf="isLoggedInForView">
     <div class="row tile-container">


         <div class="tile-art"  routerLink="/">
             <i class="fas fa-search fa-2x"></i>
         </div>  

         <div class="tile-art" routerLink="/">
             <i class="far fa-list-alt fa-2x"></i>
          </div> 

         <div class="tile-art"> 
         <confirm-modal-logout (logout)="logOut()"></confirm-modal-logout>
          </div>

      </div> 
  </div>
    <!-- main contents -->
    <div class="container-fluid inner-content login-container-height">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <app-footer *ngIf="isLoggedInForView"></app-footer>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: post your code on codePen or some other online editor?

Comment: Hy @RiyaGeorge, wellcome to stackoverflow! You could use https://stackblitz.com to genereate an angular demo to share and enable to discuss about the question

Comment: Thanks @Pablo Ezequiel . Sorry but I was not sure if I can paste the code online. I could resolve this error by commenting out the sidebar navigation call as edited in app.component.html. I am guessing sidebar navigation component had some errors (although it seemed to be working fine) which I could not trace.